# How to make changes in Docker Image linked to repository?

Tags: python, docker, go

I am facing issues while making changes to a project and building.

https://github.com/schollz/find3

I tried to clone docker image and made some changes to the files and created new image from that but no changes are reflected in the image.

I later figured out from Dockerfile that this project is cloning the online git repo and building again from scratch.

How to make changes to this project and build it in docker?

```bash
# docker build -t find3 .
# mkdir /tmp/find3
# docker run -p 11883:1883 -p 8003:8003 -v /tmp/find3:/data -t find3

FROM ubuntu:18.04

ENV GOLANG_VERSION 1.11
ENV PATH="/usr/local/go/bin:/usr/local/work/bin:${PATH}"
ENV GOPATH /usr/local/work
ENV GO111MODULE=on
# RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y upgrade && \
RUN apt-get update && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y wget git libc6-dev make pkg-config g++ gcc mosquitto-clients mosquitto python3 python3-dev python3-pip python3-setuptools python3-wheel supervisor libfreetype6-dev python3-matplotlib libopenblas-dev libblas-dev liblapack-dev gfortran
RUN python3 -m pip install Cython --install-option="--no-cython-compile" && \
    apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y python3-scipy python3-numpy && \
    mkdir /usr/local/work && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && \
    set -eux; \
    \
# this "case" statement is generated via "update.sh"
    dpkgArch="$(dpkg --print-architecture)"; \
    case "${dpkgArch##*-}" in \
        amd64) goRelArch='linux-amd64'; goRelSha256='b3fcf280ff86558e0559e185b601c9eade0fd24c900b4c63cd14d1d38613e499' ;; \
        armhf) goRelArch='linux-armv6l'; goRelSha256='8ffeb3577d8ca5477064f1cb8739835973c866487f2bf81df1227eaa96826acd' ;; \
        arm64) goRelArch='linux-arm64'; goRelSha256='e4853168f41d0bea65e4d38f992a2d44b58552605f623640c5ead89d515c56c9' ;; \
        i386) goRelArch='linux-386'; goRelSha256='1a91932b65b4af2f84ef2dce10d790e6a0d3d22c9ea1bdf3d8c4d9279dfa680e' ;; \
        ppc64el) goRelArch='linux-ppc64le'; goRelSha256='e874d617f0e322f8c2dda8c23ea3a2ea21d5dfe7177abb1f8b6a0ac7cd653272' ;; \
        s390x) goRelArch='linux-s390x'; goRelSha256='c113495fbb175d6beb1b881750de1dd034c7ae8657c30b3de8808032c9af0a15' ;; \
        *) goRelArch='src'; goRelSha256='afc1e12f5fe49a471e3aae7d906c73e9d5b1fdd36d52d72652dde8f6250152fb'; \
            echo >&2; echo >&2 "warning: current architecture ($dpkgArch) does not have a corresponding Go binary release; will be building from source"; echo >&2 ;; \
    esac; \
    \
    url="https://golang.org/dl/go${GOLANG_VERSION}.${goRelArch}.tar.gz"; \
    wget -O go.tgz "$url"; \
    echo "${goRelSha256} *go.tgz" | sha256sum -c -; \
    tar -C /usr/local -xzf go.tgz; \
    rm go.tgz; \
    \
    if [ "$goRelArch" = 'src' ]; then \
        echo >&2; \
        echo >&2 'error: UNIMPLEMENTED'; \
        echo >&2 'TODO install golang-any from jessie-backports for GOROOT_BOOTSTRAP (and uninstall after build)'; \
        echo >&2; \
        exit 1; \
    fi; \
    \
    export PATH="/usr/local/go/bin:$PATH"; \
    go version && \
    mkdir /build && cd /build && \
    git clone https://github.com/schollz/find3 && \
    mkdir /data && \
    mkdir /app && \
    echo '#!/bin/bash\n\
pkill -9 mosquitto\n\
cp -R -u -p /app/mosquitto_config /data\n\
mosquitto -d -c /data/mosquitto_config/mosquitto.conf\n\
mkdir -p /data/logs\n\
/usr/bin/supervisord\n'\
> /app/startup.sh && \
    chmod +x /app/startup.sh && echo '[supervisord]\n\
nodaemon=true\n\
[program:main]\n\
directory=/app/main\n\
command=/app/main/main -debug -data /data/data -mqtt-dir /data/mosquitto_config\n\
priority=1\n\
stdout_logfile=/data/logs/main.stdout\n\
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0\n\
stderr_logfile=/data/logs/main.stderr\n\
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=0\n\
[program:ai]\n\
directory=/app/ai\n\
command=make production\n\
priority=2\n\
stdout_logfile=/data/logs/ai.stdout\n\
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0\n\
stderr_logfile=/data/logs/ai.stderr\n\
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=0\n'\
> /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf && \
    mkdir /app/mosquitto_config && \
    touch /app/mosquitto_config/acl  && \
    touch /app/mosquitto_config/passwd  && echo 'allow_anonymous false\n\
acl_file /data/mosquitto_config/acl\n\
password_file /data/mosquitto_config/passwd\n\
pid_file /data/mosquitto_config/pid\n'\
> /app/mosquitto_config/mosquitto.conf && \
    echo "moving to find3" && cd /build/find3/server/main  && go build -v && \
    echo "moving main" && mv /build/find3/server/main /app/main && \
    echo "moving to ai" && cd /build/find3/server/ai  && python3 -m pip install -r requirements.txt && \
    echo "moving ai" && mv /build/find3/server/ai /app/ai && \
    echo "removing go srces" && rm -rf /usr/local/work/src && \
    echo "purging packages" && apt-get remove -y --auto-remove git libc6-dev pkg-config g++ gcc && \
    echo "autoclean" && apt-get autoclean && \
    echo "clean" && apt-get clean && \
    echo "autoremove" && apt-get autoremove && \
    echo "rm trash" && rm -rf ~/.local/share/Trash/* && \
    echo "rm go" && rm -rf /usr/local/go* && \
    echo "rm perl" && rm -rf /usr/share/perl* && \
    echo "rm build" && rm -rf /build* && \
    echo "rm doc" && rm -rf /usr/share/doc* 

WORKDIR /app
CMD ["/app/startup.sh"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fork the repository and change this line to point to your forked repository:

```
git clone https://github.com/schollz/find3 && \
```